# Drupal Takes Over Sibling Site?

Tags: apache-2.2

On my Mac OSX Apache server there are 2 sites, school and club, with web roots at www/school and www/club. Apache is configured via virtual hosts to serve school at school.domain.edu and club at school.domain.edu/club. The most salient difference between the two sites is that club uses a Drupal installation whereas school is written in a custom Coldfusion framework.

This configuration worked quite nicely until recently, when it seems that the Drupal installation in www/club suddenly began treating school.domain.edu/index.cfm as a node somehow, trying to load the club site's template css and modules when the school site's index is accessed, resulting in very messy page. Other pages in www/school are unaffected, only the index page seems to have been eaten by Drupal.

I don't have much Drupal experience, and I am utterly baffled how the Drupal installation in one site of a virtual host setup can hijack the other site. Does anyone have any idea what I should change to tell Drupal to stay in its own site?

Comment: This more specific to Drupal than being a webmaster and since no one has answered on webmasters, I am going to migrate it to the drupal site.

Comment: What makes you think the Drupal club site is involved?

Comment: Have you specified the base URL in the Drupal install's settings.php? (line 145 in D6). At the top of settings.php is a guide to naming conventions, in case you need to specify a non-default 'sites' folder.

Comment: Drupal on its own has no mechanisms to hijack control outside of its directory.  This is most likely an apache configuration issue, in the school.domain.edu virtualhost configuration or a .htaccess file in the directory for school.domain.edu.

Comment: Note, this question is originally from webmaster.SE

Comment: Please post the .htaccess file from the school.domain.edu directory

Comment: Can you also post the VirtualHost declarations?

Comment: Please post the exact result from
`httpd -S`

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing if you're on shared hosting or not; it smells like the NameVirtualHost might be missing. This would means that your secondary host is routing to the wrong VirtualHost (because you haven't got vhosting configured correctly).

Have a look for something like:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
# or
NameVirtualHost *:443
```